# Using <%= render comments %> always outputs an empty partial, even if there is nothing in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm starting to wonder if this is a bug with Rails 4, but I'm very new to rails and find myself smacking myself in the forehead eventually with most of the bugs I run in to. But I'm running into a wall on this one.

I have a Post. Posts have comments.

My Comment partial (/views/comments/_comment.html.erb)

```
<div class="comment-wrap">
<div class="row">
<div class="comment-meta">
    <%= comment.commenter %>
    <small><%= comment.created_at %></small>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', [comment.post, comment], method: :delete,  confirm: 'Are you sure?', class: "tiny button radius right" %>
</div>
<div class="small-2 columns">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" height="50" width="50" alt="Avatar Image"/>
</div>

<div class="small-10 columns">
  <%= comment.body %>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Here is how I render that in .../views/posts/show.html.erb

```
<h4>Leave a comment</h4>
<%= render "comments/form" %>

<h4>Comments</h4>
<%= render @post.comments %>
```

Edit:Controller .../controllers/comments/comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @post = post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end

    def destroy
        @post = post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end

    private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body, :post_id)
    end
end
```

Edit: Posts Controller

```
class postsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /posts
# GET /posts.json
def index
  @posts = post.all
end

# GET /posts/1
# GET /posts/1.json
def show
end

# GET /posts/new
def new
  @post = post.new
end

# GET /posts/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /posts
# POST /posts.json
def create
  @post = post.new(post_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'post was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /posts/1
# PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.update(post_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'post was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /posts/1
# DELETE /posts/1.json
def destroy
  @post.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_post
    @post = post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name, :description, :date, :address)
  end
end
```

This will list out the comments, but the first item is always an empty partial, with the placeholder avatar and a delete button. I've checked in rails console to see how many comments a particular post has, just to make sure there wasn't some empty record in the db, but that's not the case. Why am I getting this empty and additional partial that does not match up with a database record?

Comment: Can you post the controller action code?

Comment: Sure - just added in my comments controller. Let me know if there is anything else that might help.

Comment: Yes, `PostsController` might help.

Comment: Sure. Added. The posts controller was scaffolded when I created the app (as you can see). Thanks.

Comment: I am having a similar issue in Rails 3.2, in just one particular case. In my case, it is rendering just half of the partials HTML tags, with no data. This is really strange. Did you find any answer?

Answer (score 1):

It is because `@post.comments.build` in `comments/form.html.erb`. `build()` will always create a new empty object, and that comes before `render()`. Try replacing it with `Comment.new` so the empty comment won't be associated with the post.

Comment: Hey Chloe, your suggestion is correct but i still think this is a bug, I was able to reproduce this on personal project but instead of doing the equivalent of post.comments I just assigned comments to post.comments in the controller.  After that it still did not display correctly and errored as rapture mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the form is above the `<%= render @post.comments %>` so there is an empty comment when you reach the partial for all the comments, even if there's none in database, put the `<%= render "comments/form" %>` below to fix this.

Comment: holy crap you're a freakin genius!